# How to ignore LINQ to SQL on unique key?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I insert data with LINQ to SQL on my DB on a table where there is a unique key on 2 columns.
When I try to insert a row with this unique key already inserted, I get:

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.613_LiveLove' with
>   unique index 'IX_613_LiveLove'. The duplicate key value is
>   (35715346455553, paul). The statement has been terminated.

I don't want this error message, just "LINQ to SQL, does not insert it" and continue the process.

Is there a way on doing this? Or need I to use try/catch?

Comment: What's wrong with try/catch?

Comment: since this will only trigger in SaveChanges, it is entirly possible there is more work that is not going through because off the error. Try/catch would stop the entire block

Comment: Yep, that's why I won't to use try catch @sq33G

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are saying there's other work that would be rolled back that you want to keep even though the insert failed.  If that's the case then you don't really have a transaction that needs to be atomic.  Just do all the other work in one transaction and the insert in another. Not sure if I've quite grasped your problem though.

Comment: In MySql, there is a command "INSERT IGNORE", which does exactly this. I am aslo searching for something similar in LINQ but haven't found yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use try catch. Catch the specific exception type, and throw your own exception (you propably want to create your own exception type) including your custom message. At the location in you code you want to continue the process, just catch that exception.

Comment: The problem is that I should use try/catch on `db.SubmitChanges();`, which is unique. If I avoid one operation, the rest will be avoided...

Comment: I assmue you are using this method?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345081.aspx There you should use the appropriate ConflictMode to prevent the process from stopping.

Answer (score 1):

This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic18

"... any errors detected by the database will cause the submission process to abort and an exception will be raised. All changes to the database will be rolled back as if none of the submissions ever took place. The DataContext will still have a full recording of all changes so it is possible to attempt to rectify the problem and resubmit them by calling SubmitChanges() again..."

Comment: This means "I can't"? :)

Comment: Look at the example at that link. You can try to solve the problem (or go to the next operation if this is your case) and submit changes again: `try {
   db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception e) {
   // make some adjustments
   ...
   // try again
   db.SubmitChanges();
}`